# Multiple translate filters on the same event field in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using the following translate filters in my logstash configuration file. I have two separate YAML files that serve as the lookup dictionaries. The logstash event `field` referenced is the same for both filters but their `destination` fields are different. When I execute this, the `destination` field  from the first translate filter is populated correctly, but the `destination` filter of the second translate filter fails to populate. How do I ensure that the `destination` of the second field is also populated correctly using these multiple translate filters?

```
translate {
      dictionary_path => "C:/elk/lookupFile_1.yaml"
      field => "eventField_1"
      destination => "destField_1"
}

translate {
      dictionary_path => "C:/elk/lookupFile_2.yaml"
      field => "eventField_1"
      destination => "destField_2"
}
```

Two alternatives I think would be possible -

a) Instead of two YAML files, using just one YAML file where the `value` field is an array eg `key1 : val1a ,val1b`. Then using the dissect filter to maybe separate the destination field into separate fields.

b) Create a duplicate of `eventField_1`, say `eventField_1Copy`, and pass that to the field parameter of the second translate filter. I can then drop `eventField_1Copy`

Comment: This is already the correct way to do multiple translate based on the same source field, your second `yaml` file must have something wrong, if the first translate worked, the second should work too. Can you share the content of the files for a valeu where the translate not worked?

Comment: @leandrojmp I created a fresh yaml file and that worked! It populated the second destination field correctly. Thank you for confirming the validity of my approach.

Comment: Consider posting your comment as an answer to the question and accepting it when it worked for you.